# VBA to cut, delete and move a row to another worksheet based on cell value using command button

Tags: excel, vba

I have been working on a vba which will automatically move an entire row from the Mailing Log worksheet to the Completed Log worksheet if the values "Complete" or "Closed Incomplete" are entered into Column H using a command button in the header of Column H.

The command button is working, but for some strange reason when it pastes the row into the completed log, instead of pasting it onto the next available line, it pastes it right at the bottom of the sheet in row "1048542". also I have only managed to get it working for the value 'Complete' and not yet for Closed Incomplete.

Can someone please help?

I have attached an example of my spreadsheets and my current VBA code Is as below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Check As Range, r As Long, lastrow2 As Long, lastrow As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        lastrow = Worksheets("Mailing LOG").UsedRange.Rows.Count
            lastrow2 = Worksheets("Completed Log").UsedRange.Rows.Count
                If lastrow2 = 1 Then lastrow2 = 0
                    For r = lastrow To 2 Step -1
                        If Range("H" & r).Value = "Complete" Then
                            Rows(r).Cut Destination:=Worksheets("Completed Log").Range("A" & lastrow2 + 1)
            lastrow2 = lastrow2 + 1
            Else:
        End If
    Next r
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2i7h.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead. UsedRange doesn't always work as expected as it can include cells previously formatted. I have also added some sheet references to your code to increase clarity (and ensure your code works as expected whichever sheet is active at the time).

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Check As Range, r As Long, lastrow2 As Long, lastrow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lastrow = Worksheets("Mailing LOG").UsedRange.Rows.Count

For r = lastrow To 2 Step -1
    If Worksheets("Mailing LOG").Range("H" & r).Value = "Complete" Then
        Worksheets("Mailing LOG").Rows(r).Cut Destination:=Worksheets("Completed Log").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
    End If
Next r

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, that's brilliant, I also need to add in the value of Closed Incomplete, but when I separate "Complete" and "Incomplete using OR, this does not work.

Comment: Not sure exactly what you want to do but OR is formulated like so `If Worksheets("Mailing LOG").Range("H" & r).Value = "Complete" Or Worksheets("Mailing LOG").Range("H" & r).Value = "Closed" Then`